# "recursive value needs type" with no recursion or forward reference involved

Tags: scala

I have a code fragment in a class like this:

```
protected val reservedWords =
  this.getClass.getMethods
    .filter(_.getReturnType == classOf[Keyword])
    .map(_.invoke(this).asInstanceOf[Keyword].str)

override val lexical = {
  new SqlLexical(reservedWords)
}
```

This works fine, but `reservedWords` was only used once. So I decided to make it a local variable:

```
override val lexical = {
  val keywords =
    this.getClass.getMethods
      .filter(_.getReturnType == classOf[Keyword])
      .map(_.invoke(this).asInstanceOf[Keyword].str)

  new SqlLexical(keywords)
}
```

(`SqlLexical`'s constructor takes a `Seq[Int]`). Somehow this gives two errors:

```
[error] /home/aromanov/IdeaProjects/scalan-lite/meta/src/main/scala/scalan/meta/SqlParser.scala:186: recursive value keywords needs type
[error]       val keywords =
[error]           ^
[error] /home/aromanov/IdeaProjects/scalan-lite/meta/src/main/scala/scalan/meta/SqlParser.scala:191: not found: value keywords
[error]       new SqlLexical(keywords)
[error]                      ^
```

Replacing `val keywords = Nil` makes both errors go away. Giving an explicit type instead fixes the first error only. What is going on here?

I don't have a minimized example yet, because I hope I am missing something obvious and it won't be needed. But the complete class can be seen at https://github.com/scalan/scalan/blob/a84253df1b04bf98ab7aba43be9e661f5c9e1423/meta/src/main/scala/scalan/meta/SqlParser.scala and it should be possible to reproduce the problem by

```
git clone https://github.com/scalan/scalan.git
git checkout a84253df1b04bf98ab7aba43be9e661f5c9e1423
sbt scalan-meta/compile
```

UPDATE: if I keep the original `protected val reservedWords` in place,

```
override val lexical = {
  val keywords =
    this.getClass.getMethods
      .filter(_.getReturnType == classOf[Keyword])
      .map(_.invoke(this).asInstanceOf[Keyword].str)

  new SqlLexical(keywords)
}
```

compiles without problems.

Comment: Make it a `lazy val` or a `def`, with explicit `: Type` in its declaration

Comment: It overrides a `val`. I'll try giving an explicit signature, but 1) as the question says, giving an explicit signature to the local variable _doesn't_ help; 2) even if it works, I'd want an explanation _why_.

Comment: Specifying the type does work. Still no idea why :(

Comment: Because in case of recursive declaration, the compiler has no way to infer the type from the "lazy" body, so you have to give it explicitly.

Comment: But where is the recursion? And why there is no problem in the original version? And how `not found: value keywords` is possible when `keywords` is defined on the previous line?